# How to have defaults for environment variables in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I have set a default for environment variables under **Run > Edit Configurations...**, and still, when I make a new PyCharm project, that default is lost, and I have to set the environment variables again.

How can I set the environment variables in such a way that they affect any new PyCharm project I make?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Take a look there is a new and more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults you are editing affect only new *Run configurations* for the project you presently have open.  I'm not sure that you can change the defaults for new *projects*.  If it's even possible, I suspect you'll need to "look under the hood" in your `$HOME/.PyCharm*/config/` directory.

Answer (score 5):

While looking into this today, I found that PyCharm has multiple main locations for adding default environmental variables. While it is a pain, it will cover most use cases.

**1) Open File -> New Project Settings**

[(Image) New Project Settings Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPyIQ.png)

**2) Set default environmental variables in these two locations:**

- Tools -> Terminal
- Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console

[(Image) Terminal and Console Locations in Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRd5M.png)

**3) Set environmental variables for Run/Debug Configurations (especially for Python and Python tests)**

[(Image) Where to find configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I4Nx.png)

[(Image) Location of Python and Python Tests in Template List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMw0v.png)

---

You can always edit other templates to include your variables. These multiple locations also allow you to be specific with your variables (For example, I have my Private PyPi auth token only in the Terminal location). Hope this helps!